# How to calculate the number of months between startDate and endDate in elasticsearch if the endDate value is not present?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

The problem I'm facing right now is to calculate the range of months between "startDate" & "endDate". If the user has both of these values I'm not having any problem to calculate it but when he/she is still employed (which I get from the `isEmployed` property, which is a boolean) the "endDate" value is null which is OK but when I try to override that value I'm getting a casting error in the field `runtime_mapping`.

`index mapping`:

```
PUT {{elasticUrl}}/user-experiences
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "userId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "experienceId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "startDate": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "endDate": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`aggregation`:

```
POST {{elasticUrl}}/user-experiences/_search
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "endDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "script": {
                "source": "if (doc['isEmployed'].value == true) { emit(new Date().getTime()) } else { emit (params._source['endDate']) }"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
        "group_by": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "userId"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "start": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "startDate"
                    }
                },
                "end": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "endDate"
                    }
                },
                "duration": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "start": "start.value",
                            "end": "end.value"
                        },
                        "script": {
                            "params": {
                                "month_in_milliseconds": 2628000000
                            },
                            "source": "Math.round((params.end - params.start) / params.month_in_milliseconds)"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "duration_bucket_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "durationBucket": "duration"
                        },
                        "script": {
                            "params": {
                                "number_of_months": 1
                            },
                            "source": "params.durationBucket >= params.number_of_months"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Error message is as follows`:
`reason: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "emit (params._source['endDate']) }",
                    "                    ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "if (doc['isEmployed'].value == true) { emit(new Date().getTime()) } else { emit (params._source['endDate']) }",
                "lang": "painless",
                "position": {
                    "offset": 95,
                    "start": 75,
                    "end": 109
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "emit (params._source['endDate']) }",
                        "                    ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "if (doc['isEmployed'].value == true) { emit(new Date().getTime()) } else { emit (params._source['endDate']) }",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "position": {
                        "offset": 95,
                        "start": 75,
                        "end": 109
                    },
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "class_cast_exception",
                        "reason": "class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this issue I created a `updatedEndDate` runtime filed that is of type date and instead of the original end date in the mapping I used the runtime field in my aggregation, the solution looks something like this:

```
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "updatedEndDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "script": {
                "source": "if (doc['isEmployed'].value.equals(true)) { emit(new Date().getTime()) } else { emit(doc['endDate'].value.millis) } "
            }
        }
    }
```